# How can I disable the downloaded neural net for speech-to-text?

Tags: settings, voice-recognition

My voice-to-text was working amazing on my Pixel 3, until I elected to accept the optional downloaded neural net that makes for "faster recognition" and works offline. The result has been an astounding drop in accuracy to the point that it's unusable, and I'd like to turn the feature off and go back to normal recognition.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it, right after I put up the bounty, go figure.

Just searching "Voice typing" in settings and turn off `Faster voice typing`.